# In Ruby is there a way to overload the initialize constructor?

Tags: ruby

In Java you can overload constructors:

```
public Person(String name) {
  this.name = name;
}
public Person(String firstName, String lastName) {
   this(firstName + " " + lastName);
}
```

Is there a way in Ruby to achieve this same result: two constructors that take different arguments?

Answer (score 93, accepted):

The answer is both Yes and No.

You can achieve the same result as you can in other languages using a variety of mechanisms including:

- Default values for arguments
- Variable Argument lists (The splat operator)
- Defining your argument as a hash

The actual syntax of the language does not allow you to define a method twice, even if the arguments are different.

Considering the three options above these could be implemented with your example as follows

```
# As written by @Justice
class Person
  def initialize(name, lastName = nil)
    name = name + " " + lastName unless lastName.nil?
    @name = name
  end
end


class Person
  def initialize(args)
    name = args["name"]
    name = name + " " + args["lastName"] unless args["lastName"].nil?
    @name = name
  end
end

class Person
  def initialize(*args)
    #Process args (An array)
  end
end
```

You will encounter the second mechanism frequently within Ruby code, particularly within Rails as it offers the best of both worlds and allows for some syntactic sugar to produce pretty code, particularly not having to enclose the passed hash within braces.

This [wikibooks link](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Syntax/Method_Calls) provides some more reading

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the `Person.new(:first_name => "...", :last_name => "...")` method. For some reason it did not cross my mind to use that, but that does answer my question.

Comment: Ruby 2.0 supports named parameters out of the box: http://robots.thoughtbot.com/ruby-2-keyword-arguments

Comment: you can also subclass. e.g. `class Employee < Person` and then provide your initialization code within the employee class and call `super`. there are pros and cons. but it's an option.

Answer (score 36):

I tend to do

```
class Person
  def self.new_using_both_names(first_name, last_name)
    self.new([first_name, last_name].join(" "))
  end

  def self.new_using_single_name(single_name)
    self.new(single_name)
  end

  def initialize(name)
    @name = name
  end
end
```

But I don't know if this is the best approach.

Comment: +1: Not the best, but certainly clever. Follows Ruby's naming system.

Comment: +1 for the clever idea, though this is not overloading per definition.

Answer (score 4):

```
class Person
  def initialize(name, lastName = nil)
    name = name + " " + lastName unless lastName.nil?
    @name = name
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3):

```
class StatementItem
  attr_reader :category, :id, :time, :amount

  def initialize(item)
    case item
    when Order
      initialize_with_order(item)
    when Transaction
      initialize_with_transaction(item)
    end
  end

  def valid?
    !(@category && @id && @time && @amount).nil?
  end

  private
    def initialize_with_order(order)
      return nil if order.status != 'completed'
      @category = 'order'
      @id = order.id
      @time = order.updated_at
      @amount = order.price
    end

    def initialize_with_transaction(transaction)
      @category = transaction.category
      @id = transaction.id
      @time = transaction.updated_at
      @amount = transaction.amount
    end

end
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [konstructor](https://github.com/snovity/konstructor) gem to declare multiple constructors in Ruby and imitate overloading:

```
class Person
  def initialize(name)
    @name = name
  end

  konstructor
  def from_two_names(first_name, last_name)
    @name = first_name + ' ' + last_name
  end
end

Person.new('John Doe')
Person.from_two_names('John', 'Doe')
```

Comment: This is an underrated answer. It is very helpful for scenarios such as `MyType.parse(foo)` or `MyClass.decode(bar)` using konstructor in addition to the default constructor.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the *double splat operator* `**` in conjunction with *logical or* (double pipes) `||` inside the `initialize` method to achieve the same effect.

```
class Person
  def initialize(**options)
    @name = options[:name] || options[:first_name] << ' ' << options[:last_name]
  end
end

james = Person.new(name: 'James')
#=> #<Person @name="James">

jill_masterson = Person.new(first_name: 'Jill', last_name: 'Masterson')
#=> #<Person @name="Jill Masterson">
```

However, if a new `Person` is created without a `first_name`, then the append `<<` operation will fail with `NoMethodError: undefined method '<<' for nil:NilClass`. Here is a refactored `initialize` method to handle this case (using `strip` to remove whitespace if *either* option is excluded).

```
class Person
  def initialize(**options)
    @name = options[:name] || [ options[:first_name] , options[:last_name] ].join(' ').strip
  end
end

goldfinger = Person.new(last_name: 'Goldfinger')
#=> #<Person @name="Goldfinger">

oddjob = Person.new(first_name: 'Oddjob')
#=> #<Person @name="Oddjob">
```

In fact, this approach handles calling `Person.new` without arguments or with an unexpected key to return the new instance with `@name` set to an empty string:

```
nameless = Person.new
#=> <#Person @name="">

middle_malcom = Person.new(middle_name: 'Malcom')
#=> <#Person @name="">
```

Answer (score 1):

checkout [functional-ruby](https://github.com/jdantonio/functional-ruby) gem which is inspired by Elixir [pattern matching](http://jerrydantonio.com/functional-ruby/Functional/PatternMatching.html) features.

```rb
   class Person
     include Functional::PatternMatching

     defn(:initialize, String) { |name| 
       @name = name 
     }

     defn(:initialize, String, String) {|first_name, last_name| 
      @name = first_name + ' ' + last_name
     }
   end
```

Comment: This is an innovative way to borrow practices from another language. I'd like to see your code example more closely resemble the original poster's language using `Person`, `first_name`, and `last_name`.